# Thicken date range using padr where starting value is the same as one of the dates in data frame

Tags: r, date, padr

I am not totally sure if this is a bug or am I actually doing something wrong. But I will ask the question here and go from there.

Suppose we have a dummy data set of number of calls:

```
df_calls = data.frame(Call_date= c("2019-02-18",
                                    "2019-02-19",                                               
                                    "2019-02-20",                                               
                                    "2019-02-22",                                              
                                    "2019-02-25",                                              
                                    "2019-02-26",                                              
                                    "2019-03-01",                                              
                                    "2019-03-04"),
                      Calls = c(12,4,2,8,1,3,1,8))
```

I want to now thicken this data set and see how many calls were there per week **starting** from `"2019-02-18"`.

Thus we have:

```
starting_day= as.Date("2019-02-18")
```

Now I would expect in the week starting from day `"2019-02-18"` until day `"2019-02-24"` there should be `12+4+2+8 = 26` calls.

Let's have a look...

Using the `padr` library, I use the function `thicken`:

```
library(padr)

df_calls_weekly = df_calls %>%
                   mutate(Call_date = as.Date(Call_date)) %>% 
                   thicken("week",colname = "Date_Week" ,start_val = starting_day) %>%
                   group_by(Date_Week) %>%  
                   summarise(Num_calls = sum(Calls)) %>%
                   ungroup()
```

Looking at `df_calls_weekly` we have the following output:

```
    # A tibble: 3 x 2
      Date_Week  Num_calls
      <date>         <dbl>
    1 2019-02-18        14
    2 2019-02-25         5
    3 2019-03-04         8
```

We seem to get a different answer, that is for the week starting from `"2019-02-18"` we get **14** calls. Not 26?

Upon investigating, I see that when looking at how `thicken` creates the dataframe, it appears to drop the row where `Call_date == "2019-02-18"`. Which you can see explicitly here:

```
df_calls_weekly = df_calls %>%
  mutate(Call_date = as.Date(Call_date)) %>% 
  thicken("week",colname = "Date_Week" ,start_val = starting_day) %>%
  filter(Date_Week ==starting_day )
```

with output:

```
   Call_date Calls  Date_Week
1 2019-02-19     4 2019-02-18
2 2019-02-20     2 2019-02-18
3 2019-02-22     8 2019-02-18
```

it for whatever reason is ignoring the `Call_date` of `"2019-02-18"`. I presume this has got to do with something with the fact that the call date is the same as the `start_val` date specified in the `thicken` function.

If anyone knows how to get the thicken to include any dates which happen to be the same as the starting date parameter in `thicken`, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `start_val` argument to `thicken` is:

> By default the first instance of interval that is lower than the lowest value of the input datetime variable, with all time units on default value.

The function assuming that all other values are *strictly* greater than `start_val`, but you have the lowest values being *equal to* `start_val` and those lowest values are thereby ignored.

Here's a fix:

```r
df_calls = data.frame(Call_date= c("2019-02-18",
                                   "2019-02-19",                                               
                                   "2019-02-20",                                               
                                   "2019-02-22",                                              
                                   "2019-02-25",                                              
                                   "2019-02-26",                                              
                                   "2019-03-01",                                              
                                   "2019-03-04"),
                      Calls = c(12,4,2,8,1,3,1,8))

starting_day= as.POSIXct("2019-02-17 23:59:59") # a second before the minimum date
library(tidyverse)
library(padr)

df_calls_weekly = df_calls %>%
  mutate(Call_date = as.Date(Call_date)) %>% 
  thicken("week",colname = "Date_Week", start_val = starting_day) %>% 
  group_by(Date_Week) %>%  
  summarise(Num_calls = sum(Calls)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Date_Week = Date_Week + 1) # add the missing second back in
```